# Can I get the name of a type conforming to a protocol from that protocol?

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

I would like to know if I can find the name of a type conforming to a given protocol, from that protocol. I was thinking of protocol extension to avoid repetition in every type conforming to that protocol. I tried this:

```
protocol T {
    var type: String { get }
}

extension T {
    var type: String {
        return String(describing: T.self)
    }
}

struct S: T {}
let s = S()
print(s.type)
```

But this is showing `T` instead of `S`.

Is there any way I can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Naturally it's printing `T`, that's what you asked for with `String(describing: T.self)`. `T` is always the protocol itself.

Inside the protocol extension `Self` (capital 'S') is how you refer to the conforming type.

So the extension should be:

```
extension T {
    var typeName: String {
        return String(describing: Self.self)
    }
}
```

Aside, the built-in [`type(of:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/2885064-type) function already gives you the dynamic type of any object, so it's not clear that you really need to duplicate this functionality on your own.